# ReflectionException in RegisterListenersPass.php line 101: Class does not exist Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, listener

this is my first question, I have this error ReflectionException in RegisterListenersPass.php line 101: Class Acme\exampleBundle\Handler\AuthenticationHandler.php does not exist. I am using FOSUserBundle and Symfony 2.

In Services.xml

```
<service id="login_listener" class="%vixur.login_listener.class%">
        <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>

    </service>
```

AuthenticationHandler.php:

```
    <?php


namespace acme\exampleBundle\Handler;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

/**
 * Listener responsible to change the redirection at the end of the password resetting
 */
class AuthenticationHandler implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::SECURITY_IMPLICIT_LOGIN => 'onSecurityImplicitLogin',
        );
    }

    public function onSecurityImplicitLogin(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $url = $this->router->generate('ex_homepage');
        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
    }
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: `Acme !== acme`. Your namespaces are different, it is looking for `Acme\exampleBundle` but your actual namespace is `acme\exampleBundle`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the namespaces are right? Be carefully because you have to try to follow [Symfony coding standar](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html) (PSR-0 and PSR-4) and the names of the folders are not rigth. Has to be CamelCase.

Have you check if %vixur.login_listener.class% variable has the right value?

Comment: Thanks for quick response, the folders name are changed for privacy issues, but I am sure namespaces are correct, also I coppied another listener to this file but It does not work either.

Comment: Have you seen in the code that you are trying to use router variable that doesnt exist?

Comment: I really think there is something wrong with the path folder or the class name or the FQN that you store in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same situation and eventually found out that PHPStorm formating is changing the xml to something like this

```
<parameters>
    <parameter key="vixur.login_listener.class">
      Vixur\LoginListener
    </parameter>
</parameters>
```

while it should be

```
<parameters>
    <parameter key="vixur.login_listener.class">Vixur\LoginListener</parameter>
</parameters>
```